# How to highlight a word in the JTextArea java using different colors?

Tags: java, string, swing, jtextarea, swing-highlighter

I have a java code which requires highlighting different words in a text area using different colors. I managed to get the default blue color highlighting by

```
JTextArea textArea=new JTextArea();
textArea.setText('some text in textArea');
String tx=textArea.getText();
Highlighter h=textArea.getHighlighter();
String string_to_highlight=  "text";
int pos=tx.indexOf(string_to_highlight,0);
h.addHighlight(pos, pos+string_to_highlight.length(), DefaultHighliter.DefaultPainter);
```

Could anyone please help me to get other colors like Red, Yellow, etc.
Thanks.

Comment: Better to use a `JEditorPane`, it's designed for it

Comment: There is no need to use a JEditorPane since it used for displaying HTML.